# two titlepage on the same page

Tags: texstudio, lncs

I am trying to add two title pages on a single page on a LNCS template.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\include{file1}
\clearpage
%\setcounter{page}{398}
\title{Title 1}
\author{Author 1}
\institute{Another example..}


\maketitle\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{abstract}
    
Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah 
    
\end{abstract}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%include{file2}
\clearpage
%\setcounter{page}{398}
\title{Title 2}
\author{Author 2}
\institute{Some example..}


\maketitle\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{abstract}
    
Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah 
    
\end{abstract}
```

The code above give the following result (please look below)! Is there any chance I can, for example modify the \maketitle command or create a customized one, which doesn't automatically use \newpage? Do you have any other suggestions?

[image]

Thank you for your feedback in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporarily change the behaviour of `\newpage`:

```
\documentclass[]{lncs}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}


%\include{file1}
\clearpage
%\setcounter{page}{398}
\title{Title 1}
\author{Author 1}
%\institute{Another example..}

{
\let\newpage\relax
\maketitle\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{abstract}

Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah 

\end{abstract}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%include{file2}
%\clearpage
%\setcounter{page}{398}
\title{Title 2}
\author{Author 2}
%\institute{Some example..}


\maketitle\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{abstract}

Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah  Blah 

\end{abstract}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I replaced `\maketitle\thispagestyle{plain}` by `{\let\newpage\relax\maketitle}` and commenting `\clearpage`. It give the same behavior as your code. Thank you for your help!